# serializeObject skips file upload

Tags: javascript, forms, object, file-upload, input

I use this serializeObject function for my forms.

```
$.fn.serializeObject = function()
{
    var o = {};
    var a = this.serializeArray();
    $.each(a, function() {
        if (o[this.name] !== undefined) {
            if (!o[this.name].push) {
                o[this.name] = [o[this.name]];
            } 
            o[this.name].push(this.value || '');
        } else {
            o[this.name] = this.value || '';
        }
    });
    return o;
};`
```

I can do this for the ajax call
`$('form#changeprofileform').serializeObject();`

This works fine for the textfields I have, but when I want to upload a file, the `input type="file"` is not in the object so I cannot send it to the server to upload.

I searched around on stackoverflow but I can't really find anything that will help.

Does anyone know why this is not working and what I can do about that ?

P.S. I know it is possible to upload files with an iframe, but I want to do it this way

Thanks!

**edit**
I can ofcourse do it without the serializeObjectfunction and send all the inputs with .val, but that will not work in IE9 :(